# Cambiar color de fondo por parametro en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, programación-móvil

quien pueda echarme una mano, estoy realizando un proyecto y me gustaría saber si existe la manera de cambiar el color de un icono dependiendo del parámetro que se reciba

Tengo una vista con un botón que tiene la función de:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,ruta,arguments:ruta);
```

Para la siguiente vista tengo algo como esto:

```
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

Que utilizo para leer el argumento, lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo de la ruta, el color de mi icono cambie, pensé algo como:

```
If(route  == 'rutaX'){Color(0xff0000)}else{Color0xffffff}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en el codigo

```
    Expanded(
      child: _SingleCard(
        text: Text('hey'),
        text1: Text('data'),
        image: 'assets/images/hands.png',
        ruta: 'hand',
        color: Color(0xffF5A12E),
      ),
    ),
```

y en 'color:' Color(0xffF5A12E) quiero que sea dinamico dependiendo del argumento anterior.

Comment: En el widget expanded, puedes poner la validación en el mismo color:, tal que así: color: route == 'turuta' ? Color(0xffF5A12E) : 'tuotrocolor'.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```dart
 Expanded(
      child: _SingleCard(
        text: Text('hey'),
        text1: Text('data'),
        image: 'assets/images/hands.png',
        ruta: 'hand',
        color: route == 'route' ? Color_Si_True : Color_Si_False,
      ),
    ),
```

Cualquier duda, comenta y te hago una aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te respondió Manuel puedes hacer eso, inclusive yo creería que si los colores son más podrías crear un método, y hacer algo así:

```
Expanded(
  child: _SingleCard(
    text: Text('hey'),
    text1: Text('data'),
    image: 'assets/images/hands.png',
    ruta: 'hand',
    color: color()
  ),
),
```

Creamos el método `color`:

```
Color color(){
Color? setColor;
 switch(route){
  case ruta1:
  setColor = color1;
  break;
  case ruta2:
  setColor = color1;
  break;
  case ruta3:
  setColor = color1;
  break;
  case ruta4:
  setColor = color1;
  break;
  }
  return setColor!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un getter en tu clase:

```
get Color cardColor {
  final route = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

  switch (route) {
    case '/ruta1': return Color(0xFF......)
    case '/ruta2': return Color(0xFF......)
    case '/ruta3': return Color(0xFF......)
    default: return Color(0xFF......)
  }
}
```

Y lo usas de la siguiente manera:

```
Expanded(
  child: _SingleCard(
    text: Text('hey'),
    text1: Text('data'),
    image: 'assets/images/hands.png',
    ruta: 'hand',
    color: cardColor
  ),
),
```

**Nota:** Es una buena práctica que un widget pertenezca a una clase. En este caso, `_SingleCard` debería estar en su propia clase, así puedes hacer tu widget reutilizable y testeable.